# Filter by an element in subArray of a json

Tags: javascript

I have one array with an array inside, and I want to filter in the `content` subarray, I'm using loadash. Need to filter "Text" and my array should return all the items with "Text" in `content.title`.

```js
[{
  title: "A",
  content: [
    {
      title: "My Text",
      link: "http://google.comm",
      subCategory: "XXX",
      category: "XXX",
    },
    {
      title: "Text",
      link: "http://google.comm",
      subCategory: "XXX",
      category: "XXX",
    },
    {
      title: "another item",
      link: "http://google.comm",
      subCategory: "XXX",
      category: "XXX",
    }
  ],
},]

_.filter(myArray, function (item) {
  _.filter(item.content, function (subitem) {
    return subitem.title === "Text";
  });
});
```

I have tried the above code, but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an filtered sub-array with `.map()` and `.filter()`

```js
let arr = [{
    title: "A",
    content: [
      {
        title: "My Text",
        link: "http://google.comm",
        subCategory: "XXX",
        category: "XXX",
      },
      {
        title: "Text",
        link: "http://google.comm",
        subCategory: "XXX",
        category: "XXX",
      },
      {
        title: "another item",
        link: "http://google.comm",
        subCategory: "XXX",
        category: "XXX",
      }
    ],},]
    
let result = arr.map(el => {
   el.content = el.content.filter(({title}) => title === "Text");
   return el;
})

console.log(result);
```